# Get a field from an Array of records

Tags: php, arrays, field, average

How do I get all the values from a field in a record in an Array?

I want to make an average from a numerical score held under a specific field in an Array. The array is pulled from a form. Here is what I have so far but it just doesn't work.

```
$records = get_field('maths_month_report'); //gets all the records
$progressscore = $records['progress']; //targets the specific field in those records
echo . array_sum($progressscore)/count($progressscore) .; //divides the numbers in the field by the amount of records
```

revision: My apologies for not mentioning that the records are Arrays within the 'maths_month_report' Array. I can target specific fields in specific records with:

```
$firstrecord = $records[0];
$output = $firstrecord['progress'];
```

I just want to target all the 'progress' values so i can average them.

Comment: How exactly is your current attempt failing? Could you elaborate a little, e.g. the structure of the origin array (use the output of `print_r`)

Comment: Why is there two dots after echo? This is not required. Use var_dump($progressscore); and tell us what's the array contains?

Comment: What does it mean "doesnt work"? What exactly does $progressscore contain? What are those dots in echo for?

Comment: get_field isn't a php function, it's your own ? wordpress ?

Comment: The end result is echoed out to HTML

Comment: Sorry yes the get_field is Wordpress function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, if these are arrays within an array, you would need to build a new array:

```
$progresscore = array_column($records, 'progress')
```

PHP < 5.5:

```
$progresscore = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['progress'];
}, $records);
```

Or, just iterate yourself:

```
$sum = $count = 0;
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $sum += $record['progress'];
    ++$count;
}
echo $sum / $count;
```

Comment: So now should I have:    $records = get_field('maths_month_report'); 
    $progressscore = explode(',', $records['progress']);
    $progress =  array_sum($progressscore)/count($progressscore);

Comment: Its a multidimensional array. The records are Arrays within the Array. I just need to target the field in those Arrays

Comment: That totally did it!!! Woohoo!!! Thank you so very much in "echo $sum / count;" count is missing a $...I was at a complete brick wall. Thank you so very much for your help